# Combining metrics of multiple docker containers of same service

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2, metrics

Was wondering if this is possible.  I have an Asp net core 2.1 app that is hosted in AWS as ec2 instance.  There is an autoscale policy to bring it up to three instances if needed.

In this service I am using App.Metrics for tracking certain metrics.  This is being logged to Cloudwatch then exported via Lambda to Kibana.  The problem is that when instances are spun up in AWS, each instance starts to track and report its own metrics, even though they are the same service.  Which then gives multiple sets of logged metrics into Kibana making it difficult to monitor.

Is there anyway to combine these into one, regardless of whether instances are spun up or torn down.

Comment: Are you using the awslogs extension that is built in docker?